# ios/objective-c: Key value coding for NSNumbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-coding

I have an NSNumber that I declare as follows:

```
  NSNumber *itemid = importItem.itemid;
```

//importItem is a temporary object that is comprised from JSON via an API.

When I go to store this, however, it is throwing an exception at runtime.

```
 [record setValue:itemid forKey:@"itemid"];
```

The itemid displays as @"38" when you hold the cursor over itemid after setValue and itemid is a genuine NSNumber field of the record object.

This must be something simple, but can anyone shed some light on it?  Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: You're missing the declaration of your NSNumber. You're also not telling us what the exception is.

Comment: Hopefully you're declaring itemid as `NSNumber *itemid = @(38)` or something similar

Comment: I declare it as NSNumber.  I have also tried  NSNumber *itemid = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[importItem.itemid intValue]]; however that throws a red error.

Comment: Many APIs (sadly) return numbers as strings, not numbers. Check that you actually have a number (`[importItem.itemid isKindOfClass:[NSNumber Class]]`), and if it isn't, convert it. Also, you still haven't told us what the exception is.

Comment: How do I tell what the exception is?  It says (lldb) in the debugging pane and just a code in the other pane for a different variable than the line lit up in green

Comment: Disable breakpoints and continue, it'll show the exception in the debug pane.

Comment: caught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "itemid"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = __NSCFString; value = 41.'  OK.  SO I guess I need to convert it an NSNumber. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Many APIs (sadly) return numbers as strings, not numbers in JSON data. Check that you actually have a number (`[importItem.itemid isKindOfClass:[NSNumber Class]]` for instance), and if it isn't, convert it:

```
NSNumber *itemid = importItem.itemid;
if ([itemid isKindOfClass:[NSString Class]])
    itemid = @(itemid.intValue);
```